# Creating threads with recursion with c

Tags: c, multithreading

I have this task to implement a C program generating thread tree with ids such that the main thread pushes its id (not thread id but a global variable that is managed by semaphores) in a data structure and creates 2 more threads then terminates without passing any arguments to the threads.

It must be managed by shared variables and so on each thread pushes its id then creates 2 more threads and terminate the process stops after (`2^n`) leaves threads created and each leaf thread should push its id and print its thread tree then terminates.

I choose a binary tree and I am generating the threads but somehow the program stops after reaching the first leaf it prints its leaf tree then exit and I don't understand why: can you explain to me what am I doing wrong here and why it exists?
here is my code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>    
#include <pthread.h>
#include <semaphore.h>


typedef struct link{
    int id;
    struct link *parent;
    struct link *left;
    struct link *right;
}b_tree;


int id = 1;
int max_id = 0;
int n;
b_tree *t_tree = NULL;
sem_t sem, semp;

void *create_tree();
b_tree *new_node();
b_tree *search_tree(b_tree *, int);
void print_path(b_tree *);
void free_tree(b_tree *);

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

    int r, i;
    pthread_t tid;
    b_tree *node;
    if (argc < 2) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Missing argument\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    n = atoi(argv[1]);
    sem_init(&sem, 0, 1);
    sem_init(&semp, 0, 1);
    for(i = 0; i <= n; i++){
        max_id+=(int)pow(2,i);
    }
    node = new_node();
    node->id = id;
    t_tree = node;
    id++;
    for (i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        r = pthread_create(&tid, NULL, create_tree(), NULL);
        if(r){
            fprintf(stderr, "Thread creation failed\n");
            exit(1);
        }
    }
    pthread_exit(NULL);
}

b_tree *new_node(){
    b_tree *node;
    node = (b_tree *)malloc(sizeof(b_tree));
    if(node == NULL){
        fprintf(stderr, "Memory allocation error\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    node->left = NULL;
    node->right = NULL;
    node->id = -1;
    node->parent = NULL;
    return node;
}

b_tree *search_tree(b_tree *root, int key){
    b_tree *l = NULL, *r = NULL;
    if(root == NULL){
        return NULL;
    }
    if(root->id == key){
        return root;
    }
    l = search_tree(root->left, key);
    r = search_tree(root->right, key);
    if(l != NULL && l->id == key){
        return l;
    }else if(r != NULL && r->id == key){
        return r;
    }
    return NULL;
}

void *create_tree(){
    b_tree *node;
    int pid, i, r;
    pthread_t tid;
    node = new_node();
    //Enter the critical section
    sem_wait(&sem);
    if(id <= max_id){
        node->id = id;
        id++;
    }
    sem_post(&sem);
    //Exit from the critical section
    pid = (int)node->id/2; //compute the parent id
    //get parent and connect the tree
    node->parent = search_tree(t_tree, pid);
    if(node->parent != NULL){
        if(node->parent->left == NULL){
            node->parent->left = node;
        }else{
            node->parent->right = node;
        }
    }else{
        fprintf(stderr, "No parent found\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    //Check if it is a leaf
    if(node->id >= pow(2,n) && node->id <= max_id){
        sem_wait(&semp);
        print_path(node);
        sem_post(&semp);
        if(node->id == max_id){ //if it is the last leaf
            free_tree(t_tree);
        }
    }else{//not a leaf
        for(i = 0; i < 2; i++){//create 2 more threds and terminate
            r = pthread_create(&tid, NULL, create_tree(), NULL);
            if(r > 0){
                fprintf(stderr, "Thread creation failed\n");
                exit(1);
            }
        }
        printf("This node was not a leaf and it created 2 more threads\n");
    }
    pthread_exit(NULL);
}

void print_path(b_tree *leaf){
    if(leaf != NULL) printf("Thread tree: ");
    while(leaf != NULL){
        printf("%d ", leaf->id);
        leaf = leaf->parent;
    }
    printf("\n");
    return;
}

void free_tree(b_tree *root){
    if(root == NULL){
        return;
    }
    free_tree(root->left);
    free_tree(root->right);
    free(root);
    return;
}
```

Comment: What you’re doing wrong, that’s difficult to understand? Using recursion, probably.

Comment: @barny what I am trying to do is make each thread access the global variable id using mutual exclusion by a semaphore take its current value then increment it and creates a node in the tree search for its parent and connect it then check if it is a leaf thread if so it prints the path using the print_path method, else it creates 2 new threads and terminates

Comment: I’m imagining the conclusion of your task is that recursion is very very very very difficult to design successfully, to understand, to debug, to maintain. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

If you want your program to wait for the threads to complete you must call `pthread_join(pthread_t)` with the `id` of the thread you want to wait for (both I guess). Then you should call I think the same function also inside your thread function to wait for the newly created thread.

All this seems very dangerous to me so be careful.

Also note one thing: the threads and also your main program are doing exactly the same thing. Have you considered using a `fork()` to create processes instead of threads?

Comment: Thank you for responding, The task requires the thread to terminate after it adds its id to the tree and creates exactly 2 sub-threads and shouldn't wait for them to terminate that's why I don't use `pthread_join()` and the main uses `pthread_exit()` so it doesn't kill other threads and about using `fork()` the requirements is to do it with threads.

Comment: What I wanted to say is: after the first two threads are created in the `main` you are calling `pthread_exit()` which is making the main thread exiting hence terminating the program: this will terminate the entire program whethear or not the other threads are complete. The reason you don't see the other threads being generated is that your program exited before there was time to create them. You can try to add a delay before exit and check if other threads will be created.

Comment: I did what you said but gives me the same result, anyway shouldn't `bthread_exit()` terminate only the main thread without killing the other threads leaving them running.

Comment: what are the libraries for `inorder_visit` and `create_tree`? I will try the code

Comment: Thank you, it was a helper function to print the tree for me I forgot to delete it i will edit the code now

Comment: Thank you I found the error,  in the pthread_create i was using the return value of the create tree function not the pointer to the function.

Answer (score 0):

Few problems here.

- `t_tree` is initialized once in `main`, is never modified after that, and is `free`d potentially many times (see the next bullet).
- `create_tree()` assigns `node->id` only when `id <= max_id`. By the time the test

  ```
      if(node->id >= pow(2,n) && node->id <= max_id)
  ```

  is executed, the `node->id` could be uninitialized.
- It is also possible that `inorder_visit()` (not defined in the post) may cause undefined behavior.

Comment: Thank you I will modify them and the main error was me using the return value of the function pthread_create not the pointer to the function.

Answer (score 0):

The main Problem was in the `pthread_create()` where I used the value returned but the function as an argument instead of using the pointer to the function itself.
`pthread_create(&tid, NULL, create_tree, NULL);`